# Unable to access JSON property with hyphen “-” in React Js(Babel)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I'm building a small React components (compile with Babel). I have to access property with a dash inside the name.

```
this.setState({
  newArtist: {
    birthdate: artist.life-span.begin
  }
});
```

This code throw an error **Uncaught ReferenceError: span is not defined**

After some research, I found out that I need to use a alternative notatio using bracket. **['life-span']**

```
this.setState({
  newArtist: {
    birthdate: artist['life-span']begin
  }
});
```

But this one make Babel to throw a syntax error.

**bundle.js:1 SyntaxError: /file/path: Unexpected token, expected , (24:38) while parsing file**

So I'm stuck here.

My babel configuration is quite lite, only use the es2015 & react preset.

Any idea what it could be ?

Comment: Add `.` before `begin` - `artist['life-span'].begin`

Comment: @AlexanderT. Or for consistency: `artist['life-span']['begin']`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
birthdate: artist['life-span'].begin
```

instead of  `birthdate: artist['life-span']begin`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's fixed my issue!

Answer (score 0):

You must understand basics like that: properties must be qouted and rounded by square brackets, or start from dot.
So in properties chain:

```
var propNameInVar = "prop5";
object   ["prop1"]   .prop2   [3]   .prop4   [propNameInVar]   .prop6
```